# List rows with specific columns with a specific value in R from dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset called "flights" and I am attempting to list all the rows that have the value of "Escanaba, Michigan" in the column Destination. I would like to show 5 columns and then all the rows that apply to Escanaba.

Currently I have...

```
flights[,c("FlightDate","Carrier","Destination","DestCityName","AirTime")]
```

That works perfectly for what I want, except it shows all rows.

How do I call out a specific value from a column in a dataset?

Comment: Try `flights[flights$Destination %in%  "Escanaba, Michigan", c("FlightDate","Carrier","Destination","DestCityName","AirTime")]`

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty basic indexing question (see e.g [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Basics/Indexing_into_a_data_structure/), which was the first hit when I googled "R indexing"); you need to construct a logical vector that is `TRUE` for the relevant rows.

```
flights[flights$Destination=="Escanaba, Michigan",
   c("FlightDate","Carrier","Destination","DestCityName","AirTime")]
```

A prettier alternative for interactive work (not entirely safe for programmatic use):

```
subset(flights,Destination=="Escanaba, Michigan",
     select=c(FlightDate,Carrier,
              Destination,DestCityName,AirTime))
```

If you want to allow for more than one possible value of `Destination`, try `%in%`